# Extracting subtitles from YouTube live streams

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api, subtitle

Is there a way to extract the subtitle text from a **live** YouTube video?
Most often these are the auto-generated subtitles.

I note the timedtext is embedded in the videoplayback api response, rather than a timedtext response which is used for non-live videos which are easy to download.

I understand I can download them after the stream is finished (and after YouTube has regenerated subtitles based on the reprocessed video). But time is of essence and I'm hoping to extract the subtitle text while the video is live.

Thanks

[image: XHR request]